# Probability of 2 cards have the same suit

Tags: probability, permutations

Here is the question: there is a standard deck of 52 cards with 4 suits. The values are 2<3<...<10<jack<queen<king<ace. 2 cards are drawn at random without being placed back. What is the probability that the 2 cards have the same suit?

I think there's 52 card in total to pick. But the first card is picked, and there's 51 cards left. To have same suit, it's 13 cards in a suit. But the first card is already picked, so it's 12 cards in a suit. The probability is 12/51, right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.